# How to fix pandoc conversion failed with error 61

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc

I recently updated R to 3.6.0 since then i can't knit any of my .RMD files without getting "Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 61".  I have searched and googled everything i can think of and can't find a solution.  I also have no idea how i would get a recreatable file, but was hoping someone has seen this error or knows how to fix it?

```
Could not fetch http://?/UNC/ad/userfiles/***/R/R-3.6.0/library/rmarkdown/rmd/h/default.html
HttpExceptionRequest Request {

host                 = ""

port                 = 80

secure               = False

requestHeaders       = []

path                 = "/"

queryString          = "?/UNC/ad/userfiles/***/R/R-3.6.0/library/rmarkdown/rmd/h/default.html"
method               = "GET"

proxy                = Nothing

rawBody              = False

redirectCount        = 10

responseTimeout      = ResponseTimeoutDefault

requestVersion       = HTTP/1.1

}

(InvalidDestinationHost "")

Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 61
```

Comment: Looks somewhat like [this pandoc issue with UNC paths](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/5127).... not sure which pandoc version rmarkdown/rstudio ships with... can you try with pandoc 2.7.2?

Answer (score 1):

This problem stems (at least in my case) from the fact that the used `rmarkdown` library is a network folder (in your case `/UNC/ad/userfiles/***/R/R-3.6.0/library/rmarkdown/rmd/h/default.html`). R cannot access this folder because rights are missing.

You have to change your default library to a place where you have full rights. For example "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.2/library".

In RStudio, click on `Tools > Install Packages..` 
Under`"Install to library" you can see the default option (in your case it should be`/UNC/ad/userfiles/***/R/R-3.6.0/library/rmarkdown/rmd/h/default.html`). The second option here should be "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.2/library".

To change this order, i.e. to make the `C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.2/library` (on Windows) or `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resouirces/library` (on macOS) folder the default folder, you have to use the following code (execute the code in a new R file) :

```
bothPaths <- .libPaths()   # extract both paths
bothPaths <- c(bothPaths [2], bothPaths [1])  # change order
.libPaths(bothPaths )  # modify the order
```

After that, you might have to install the markdown package again. This time, it will be directly installed into the "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.2/library" folder.

Now, knitting should be working, because R will use the package straight from a folder where you have full rights.

Comment: After making the changes and reinstalling the package the `R` Session should be restarted, to ensure proper unloading of the previously installed version of the package.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue, since I upgraded de R 3.6 (using Ubuntu 18.04 64 bits, in case it matters)

```
Could not fetch
https://tiles.bcn.cat/tiles/XYZ/GuiaBCN/18/132633/97883.png

HttpExceptionRequest Request {   
host                 = "tiles.bcn.cat"   
port                 = 443   
secure               = True   
requestHeaders       = []   
path                 = "/tiles/XYZ/GuiaBCN/18/132633/97883.png"   
queryString          = ""  
method               = "GET"   
proxy                = Nothing  
rawBody              = False   
redirectCount        = 10  
responseTimeout      = ResponseTimeoutDefault
requestVersion       = HTTP/1.1 
}  
(InternalException (HandshakeFailed (Error_Protocol ("certificate has unknown CA",True,UnknownCa)))) Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 61
```

As a result to hit knit on this document:
https://gitlab.ajuntament.bcn/omd-gid/1905_pro_308_omd_curs_de_mapes_amb_r_modern_-_edicio_2020/blob/master/codi/09.mapes.Rmd#L1234

(anchor is to where that tile server is being called within the Rmd file)

Current pandoc (with R 3.6) is pandoc 1.19.2.4
Compiled with pandoc-types 1.17.0.5, texmath 0.9.4.4, skylighting 0.3.3.1
Which seems to be a bit old (Copyright (C) 2006-2016 John MacFarlane)

BTW, shall I open a new question on stack overflow, or maybe it's ok to place it here since it's somewheat related to yours, and we have both potentially related items aggregated together?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and struggled for a while. I was behind a proxy (Windows 10) using Rstudio 1.3.1073 and R 4.0.3.

In my case additional "Invalid scheme" error revealed what was wrong. The automatic proxy setting did not have "http://" -part (scheme part) as needed by pandoc.

I added in .Renviron:

`R_USER="C:\Users\myUserName\Documents"`

`http_proxy=http://my.proxy:8080`

After restarting R, I was finally able to knit html-output with styled table (kable/kableExtra).

Apparently, one should not define a https_proxy.